# How do I save/reopen data using json?

Tags: python

I have a program that works 100%. The program is supposed to saves data to a dictionary in a file so that when you close the program and relaunch it later the data is still there and editable. The problem is it stores the data, but when you relaunch the program you can only see it when you hit 5 (Print Inventory Report) the data is not editable. How do I fix this? I don't know if it matters or not but I am on a Mac.

Program Code:

```
import os
import json

class Inventory:
    def __init__(self):
        #AT LAUNCH GROUPS AND LOADING FUNCTION
        self.items = {}
        self.load()

    def remove(self, ID):
        #REMOVING ITEMS FOR LISTS AND OUTPUT DOCUMENT
        del self.items[ID]
        self.save()

    def add(self, ID, name, qty):
        #ADDING ITEMS FOR LISTS AND OUTPUT DOCUMENT
        self.items[ID] = {"name": name, "qty": qty}
        self.save()

    def update(self, ID, update):
        #UPDATING ITEMS FOR LISTS AND OUTPUT DOCUMENT
        self.items[ID]["qty"] += update
        self.save()

    def search(self, ID):
        #SEARCHING ITEMS FOR LISTS
        item = self.items.get(ID, None)
        if item:
            return ID, item['name'], item['qty']
        else:
            return None

    def __str__(self):
        #FORMATTING
        out = ""
        for id, d in self.items.items():
            out += f"ID Number : {id} \nItem Name : {d['name']}\nQuantity : {d['qty']}\n"
            out += "----------\n"
        return out
    
    def save(self):
        #WHERE TO SAVE TO
        with open('data.txt','w') as outfile:
           json.dump(self.items, outfile)

    def load(self):
        #WHERE TO PUT DATA FROM WHEN RELAUNCHING PROGRAM
        try:
            with open('data.txt','r') as json_file:
               self.items = json.load(json_file)
        except:
            print("Can't load old inventory, starting fresh")
            self.items = {}


def menuDisplay():
    #MENU FOR PROGRAM 
    """Display the menu"""
    print('=============================')
    print('= Inventory Management Menu =')
    print('=============================')
    print('(1) Add New Item to Inventory')
    print('(2) Remove Item from Inventory')
    print('(3) Update Inventory')
    print('(4) Search Item in Inventory')
    print('(5) Print Inventory Report')
    print('(99) Quit')


def add_one_item(inventory):
    #ADDING PROMPT AND ERROR CHECKING
    print('Adding Inventory')
    print('================')
    while True:
        try:
            new_ID = int(input("Enter an ID number for the item: "))
            if inventory.search(new_ID):
                print("ID number is taken, please enter a different ID number")
                continue
            new_name = input('Enter the name of the item: ').lower()
            assert new_name.isalpha(), "Only letters are allowed!"
            new_qty = int(input("Enter the quantity of the item: "))
            inventory.add(new_ID, new_name, new_qty)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again! " + str(e))
            print()


def remove_one_item(inventory):
    #REMOVING PROMPT AND ERROR CHECKING
    print('Removing Inventory')
    print('==================')
    removing = int(input("Enter the item's ID number to remove from inventory: "))
    inventory.remove(removing)


def ask_exit_or_continue():
    #OPTION TO CONTINUE OR QUITE PROGRAM
    return int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))


def update_inventory(inventory):
    #UPDATING PROMPT AND ERROR CHECKING
    print('Updating Inventory')
    print('==================')
    ID = int(input("Enter the item's ID number to update: "))
    update = int(input("Enter the updated quantity. Enter 5 for additional or -5 for less: "))
    inventory.update(ID, update)


def search_inventory(inventory):
    #SEARCHING PROMPT AND ERROR CHECKING
    print('Searching Inventory')
    print('===================')
    search = int(input("Enter the ID number of the item: "))
    result = inventory.search(search)
    if result is None:
        print("Item not in inventory")
    else:
        ID, name, qty = result
        print('ID Number: ', ID)
        print('Item:     ', name)
        print('Quantity: ', qty)
        print('----------')


def print_inventory(inventory):
    #PRINT CURRENT LIST OF ITEMS IN INVENTORY
    print('Current Inventory')
    print('=================')
    print(inventory)


def main():
    #PROGRAM RUNNING COMMAND AND ERROR CHECKING
    inventory = Inventory()
    while True:
        try:
            menuDisplay()
            CHOICE = int(input("Enter choice: "))
            if CHOICE in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
                if CHOICE == 1:
                    add_one_item(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 2:
                    remove_one_item(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 3:
                    update_inventory(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 4:
                    search_inventory(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 5:
                    print_inventory(inventory)
                exit_choice = ask_exit_or_continue()
                if exit_choice == 99:
                    exit()
            elif CHOICE == 99:
                exit()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again!"+str(e))
            print()

        # If the user pick an invalid choice,
        # the program will come to here and
        # then loop back.


main()
```

The first time you run the program it will display the error message of: "Can't load old inventory, starting fresh". This is fine. Please ask questions if need be.

Comment: I'm not reading all that. if you have questions about the json module, there is a lot of documentation online

Comment: I guess the simple version is I have a program, it saves data but when relaunching the program I can't edit the data.

Comment: you can't just reload the json and then edit it?

Comment: it only reads it, but I can't edit it.

Comment: Try to remove parts of the program that aren't related to causing the problem, until you have a minimal example. see http://sscce.org.

Comment: Also: did you try to look at the .json file in a text editor between runs of the program? Does it look like what you expected it to look like?

Comment: When you say you "can't edit it", what happens when you try to edit it? I.e., what happens when you select the editing option from the menu?

Comment: Karl I believe the error is in def save or def load.

Comment: @PaulAllen20002 why can you not edit it?

Comment: it won't show up. if ID is 111 and saves. I then close the program and relaunch it. Then type in 2 for remove and type in 111. I get a 111 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a type problem. You're trying to use an integer as a dict key to make the call. You need to cast it to a string first. For instance, in remove instead of:

```
del self.items[ID]
```

...you need:

```
del self.items[str(ID)]
```

Comment: That worked great for remove and update, but how do I do the same for the search function?

Comment: The same way: ```item = self.items.get(str(ID), None)```
items.get() also takes a string.